# How to check whether form of react redux form is valid or not?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

```
const selectFormAndCheckDirty  = () => (state) => isDirty('basic')(state);
const selectFormAndCheckPristine  = () => (state) => isPristine('basic')(state);
const selectFormAndValid  = () => (state) => isValid('basic')(state);
```

I have written this code in my selector.js

I imported in my index.js as

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    valid: selectFormAndValid(),
    dirty: selectFormAndCheckDirty(),
    pristine: selectFormAndCheckPristine()
});
```

And used it as

```
const valid = this.props.valid;
```

The const valid always return true even if form is invalid. Is there something i am missing??